# PHP/MySQL & Wordpress database error: [Unknown column '0' in 'field list']

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a row. `$requestAr['productId']` contains an integer and `$requestAr['layoutId']` contains a string. It's one line of code:

```
$wpdb->insert('strategyLayouts', ['productId' => $requestAr['productId'], $requestAr['layoutId'] ] );
```

for which I get:

```
WordPress database error: [Unknown column '0' in 'field list']
INSERT INTO `strategyLayouts` (`productId`, `0`) VALUES ('233', 'dfff')
```

Comment: You need to specify column name as key for "$requestAr['layoutId']"

Comment: please mark as complete ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$requestAr['layoutId'] is giving zero as error in the column list stated that .

```
WordPress database error: [Unknown column '0' in 'field list']
INSERT INTO `strategyLayouts` (`productId`, `0`) VALUES ('233', 'dfff')
```

Your query

```
$wpdb->insert('strategyLayouts', ['productId' => $requestAr['productId'], $requestAr['layoutId'] ] );
```

Comment: oops. Forgot the second field name.